# Auto fill recorded data file for chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, auto-form-fill

I have auto fill option activated on my chrome browser. I use Windows 7. I ma looking for the file that stores the data previously recorded as "Auto Fill" such as login username.

I know that such data is stored in C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome.

But there are so many files in it and I have already wasted a lot of time looking. Can some one point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have tried this myself:
The file you seek is a SQLite-database, so we need to download/install/use a SQLite-browser.
I used [DB browser for SQLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser), this one is easy to use. There are many others though, just choose one.

Open the DB-browser and open the <strike>database-</strike>file named "Web Data", in the following directory:

C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\{profile}

{profile} is by default "Default"

Within this database you find several tables, "autofill" is the one with the data you seek.
You may modify/delete entries within this table.

Comment: I know about the sqlite. But could you be more specific. As I said have already checked those folder. I have found so many .db files and none contained the autofill table.

Comment: The Web Data-file doesn't have an extension. It is **NOT** "Web Data.db", is it just "Web Data"